# Why doesn't Mockito's when() get triggered?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I need to test a service class, but when I try to mock the dao class, it doesn't get triggered, thus not able to use ThenReturn().

I think that the problem is because I use an interface for my Dao and @Autowired in the service class (Spring MVC 3.1):

The interface:

```
public interface TestDao {
    int createObject(Test test) throws NamingException;
}
```

The implementation:

```
@Repository
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {

    @Override
    public int createObject(Test test) {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new InsertNewTest(test), keyHolder);
        return ((java.math.BigDecimal)keyHolder.getKey()).intValue();
    }
}
```

The service:

```
public class RegTest {
    @Autowired
    TestDao testDao;

    public int regTest(int .....) {
        .
        .
        int cabotageId = testDao.createObject(test);
    }
}
```

In the test I have:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestRegService {
    @InjectMocks
    private RegTest regTest = new RegTest();

    @Mock
    TestDao testDao;

    @Test()
    public void test() {
        .
        when(testDao.createObject(null)).thenReturn(100);
        .
    }
```

testDao.createObject(null) returns 0 (due to being mock'ed) and not 100 as I is trying to achieve.

Can anybody help, please?

## Problem solved!

It was the passing test-object to createObject() that did not match. Using

```
testDao.createObject(any(Test.class))
```

did the trick!

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but when I did it, I got the appropriate return value.  How are you checking the result of createObject?  You could, after your `when` call, simply `System.out.println(testDao.createObject(null))` and see what it says.  If it says 100, then you know the problem is with the test, not the mock.  If it says 0, then it is some kind of bug with Mockito.

Comment: Hmm... It says 0 :-( I'll try the other suggestions before I report it as a bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your test is actually passing a value to createObject, then `when(testDao.createObject(null)`... never gets matched. Rather than matching on null, you could match any instance of `Test` with `testDao.createObject(any(Test.class))`...

Also when you tried later to supply `new Test()` as the argument to match, it will literally try to match on that exact instance of `Test`, but presumably your real code is new-ing up a different one. So the use of `Matchers.any(Test.class)` as the parameter to match is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito injection mechanism don't know about Spring @Autowired or CDI @Inject annotations. It just tries to find the best candidate given the type and the name of the mock, and it can lookup private fields too. See the javadoc of @InjectMocks : http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

The semantic you are using is correct, though if you are experiencing issues, I would rather look for incorrect interactions or incorrect arguments.

Are you sure the `test` variable in `regTest.regTest(int...)` is really `null` when passed to `testDao.createObject(test)` ?

Comment: No, it's an Test() object. I have tried to supply it with a `new Test()` instead of `null`, but same result

Comment: well if your test is actually passing a value, then `when(testDao.createObject(null)...` never gets matched.  Rather than matching on null, you could match any instance of Test with `testDao.createObject(any(Test.class))...`

Comment: Kevin, the any() matcher did the trick. Please create an answer and I will accept yours if you want :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a typo in the example, but you have `RegTest.regTest()` calling `createTest()` rather than `createObject()`.  Otherwise, I don't think @Autowired has anything to do with it, since your test itself is not running in a container with Spring management.  If it is not a typo, and `createTest` is in fact a real and different method from `createObject`, then the default behaviour of a mocked object in Mockito is to return the appropriately-typed zero for numeric return types.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're right about the autowire not getting called. You could inject the dao yourself using the setTestDao() call instead. Mockito also supports [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Spy.html) which allows you to trace the objects code and just replace functions instead.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Spring MVC and Mockito, so a little help about injecting or using @Spy would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Autowire tells Spring to look for a configuration for TestDao and set RegTest to that object. However unit tests don't use Sprint so testDao is never set to an object. You can setup the test yourself to have a TestDao. You might want to look up _reverse dependance injection_ here on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5643702/369446) or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).